# Прерывается выполнение скрипта при вводе текста

Tags: javascript, setinterval, localstorage

Есть скрипт который через `setInterval` периодически опрашивает `localStorage` и добавляет его содержимое к тексту в `textarea`. Но если вручную ввести текст в `textarea` то скрипт перестает работать, с чем это может быть связано и как это исправить?

Код обработчика:

```
var smile;
var isFirstLaunch = true;   

function checkSmile() {
    if( isFirstLaunch == true) {
        localStorage.setItem('current_smile', "empty");
        isFirstLaunch = false;
    }
    smile = localStorage.getItem('current_smile');
    smile = smile.trim(smile);
    if(smile != "empty") {
        addSmile();
        localStorage.setItem('current_smile', "empty");
    }

}

function addSmile() {
    smile = smile.trim(smile);
    msg = $('textarea[name="message"]').html();
    $('textarea[name="message"]').html( msg + " " + smile + " ");
}
setInterval(checkSmile, "100");
```

Скрипт сохраняющий код смайла в `localStorage`:

```
$('td').click(function(){
    var smile_code = $(this).children('div').children('table').children('tbody').children('tr:last').children('td').children('spann').html();
    localStorage.setItem('current_smile', smile_code);
 });
```

JavaScript начал учить недавно, так что прошу прощение за качество кода.

Comment: Связано это, скорее всего, с ошибкой в JS-коде. Исправить это можно, исправить эту ошибку в коде. Так как необходимый код в вопрос вы не добавили, то это максимум из того, что можно сказать о вашей проблеме.

Comment: Покажите код, как опрашивает, как вносит? Есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера при автоматическом заполнении и при заполнении пользователем? Есть ли обработчик _onchange_ на _textarea_? если есть может в нем просто останавливают интервал

Comment: в текущем коде `smile` всегда _empty_ поэтому ничего не добавляется

Comment: Смайлы добавляются до тех пор, пока не написать что-либо в textarea  вручную

Comment: Значит вы привели не весь код, фиддле код из поста, и он ничего не добавляет: http://jsfiddle.net/qc64v8oa/

Comment: Скрипт поделен на 2 части, одна вытаскивает код смайла из одной определенной страницы и сохраняет его в localStorage

Сейчас добавлю код второго скрипта

Comment: вы точно никаких обработчиков на textarea не добавляли?

Comment: и тогда уже html тоже давайте

Comment: да, воспроизвел: http://jsfiddle.net/qc64v8oa/1/

Comment: Пишу эти скрипты для стороннего сайта, так что не могу сказать - прерывает ли onChange или нет. Хотя, если судить по фиддлу, дело не в этом

Comment: тут скорее проблема в `.html()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в использовании [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/), вместо него для получения текущего значения textarea и соответственно установки нового - нужно использовать [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/).

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qc64v8oa/3/)

Html:

```
<textarea name="message"></textarea> 
<button type="button" id="btn">Smile</button>
```

Js:

```
var smile;
var isFirstLaunch = true;   
$('#btn').click(
    function(){
        localStorage.setItem('current_smile', 'smile');
    }
);
function checkSmile() {
    if( isFirstLaunch == true) {
        localStorage.setItem('current_smile', "empty");
        isFirstLaunch = false;
    }
    smile = localStorage.getItem('current_smile');
    smile = smile.trim(smile);
    if(smile != "empty") {
        addSmile();
        localStorage.setItem('current_smile', "empty");
    }

}

function addSmile() {
    smile = smile.trim(smile);
    msg = $('textarea[name="message"]').val();
    $('textarea[name="message"]').val( msg + " " + smile + " ");
}
setInterval(checkSmile, 1000);
```